# Given an array of integers, find the two elements that sum closest to 0.

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm solving this problem where

**Problem:**

> Given an array of integers, find the two elements that sum closest to
>   0.

My NativeJS solution:

```js
var a = [1,3,4,-1,-2,4,5,-9];

function sumZero(arr){
  var temp=null;
  var result=null;
  arr.forEach(function(val, i){
    if(i===0){
      temp = (a[i]+a[i+1]);
      result = i;
    } else if(temp > a[i] + a[i+1]){
      temp = (a[i]+a[i+1]);
      result = i;
    }
  });
  return result;
}

sumZero(a); // index 6 and 7 (result, result+1)

//Implementation using reduce
function sumZero2(arr){
  arr.reduce(function(temp, val, i){
    //console.log(i);
    if(temp > a[i]+a[i+1])
      return i;
  }, 0);
}
```

I'm getting the correct results using native implementation but I couldn't solve the problem using reduce.

Can someone help me withe my logic?

Comment: If the native implementation returns `6`, how is that the correct result? Wouldn't the correct result be `1` and `-1` (i.e., index of `0` and `3`)?

Comment: Please describe what you are doing closest to `0` would be 1 & -1 in my opinion, and please describe what the output should look like

Comment: The two elements whose sum is closest to zero are `1` and `-1`. Otherwise there must be the word _adjacent_ in the task description.

Comment: `a[0] + a[3] = 1 + -1 = 0` So indices 0 and 3 should be answer

Comment: sooo, the output should be an array of `[ idx1, idx2 ]` or what?

Comment: Check out my answer, however, reduce is not a good fit for that operation the `forEach` loop is fine.

Comment: @JoshCrozier I think you are right. I'm basically comparing it to nearest neighbors and then declaring which neighbor is closest to zero. (But I don't think that's the Ask)

Answer (score 1):

Below's a naive quadratic-time, constant-space solution in Javascript. I'm assuming the array contains at least two elements and for the sake of clarity avoid various sanity checks. These edge cases are easily handled.

```
function diff(arr, p) {
    return Math.abs(arr[p[0]] + arr[p[1]]);
}

function isBetter(arr, p1, p2) {
    return diff(arr, p1) < diff(arr, p2);
}

function sumZero(arr){
    let bestPair = [0, 1];
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (isBetter(arr, [i, j], bestPair)) {
                bestPair = [i, j];
            }
        }
    }
    return bestPair;
}
```

The algorithm is correct simply because it searches through all {n choose 2} pairs of elements of the array and, as it searches the space of pairs, keeps track of the best one. After the loops terminate, bestPair is the pair of indices of the array arr that sum closest to one (among all pairs of elements of arr).

Comment: I think you should correct the `diff` function as `return Math.abs(arr[p[0]] + arr[p[1]]);`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it right..

```js
function closestZeroPairFirstIndex(a) {
  var idxResult = null;
  var temp = Infinity;

  a.forEach(function(i, idx, arr) {
    var sum = Math.abs(i + (arr[idx + 1] || 0));
    if (sum < temp) {
      temp = sum;
      idxResult = idx;
    }
  });

  return idxResult;
}

console.log(closestZeroPairFirstIndex([10,2,7,-4,5,6,7]))
console.log(closestZeroPairFirstIndex([10,2,7,-4,5,-7,7])) 
console.log(closestZeroPairFirstIndex([10,2,-7,-4,5,-5,-7]))
```

Comment: Just a query,  what does your snippet returns? Should it not be a pair?

Comment: It returns the first index, as i understood the second item should be the neighbor

Answer (score 0):

You may do as follows;

```js
function getAbsoluteMinSum(arr){
  return arr.map((e,i,a) => a.slice(i+1)
                             .reduce((r,c) => Math.abs(e + c) < r.sum ? (r.sum = e + c, r.summand = c, r)
                                                                      : r, {val: e, sum: Infinity, summand: void 0}))
            .reduce((p,c) => Math.abs(p.sum) < Math.abs(c.sum) ? p : c);
}

var a = [1,3,4,-1,-2,4,5,-9];
  res = getAbsoluteMinSum(a);
console.log(res);
```

In case there are multiple pairs giving the same minimum sum, this code will give you only the last satisfying item. If you want a list of all pairs that sum up to the available minimum sum then you have to change the last `reduce` into an accumulating one.

Another approach would be;

```js
function getAbsoluteMinSum(a){
  var hash = {},
         i = 0,
         j = 0,
         c,d;
  while(i < a.length){
    j = i+1;
    c = a[i++];
    while(j < a.length){
      d = a[j++];
      hash[c+d] = hash[c+d] ? hash[c+d].concat([[c,d]])
                            : [[c,d]];
    }
  }
  return hash[Math.min(...Object.keys(hash).map(Math.abs))];
}

var a = [1,3,4,-1,-2,4,5,-9,2,-4];
  res = getAbsoluteMinSum(a);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple algo:

- Create a processed array to hold summation of 2 values.
- Now just sort it and get necessary values.

A minor optimisation would to start inner loop from index of parent loop.

```js
var a = [1,3,4,-1,-2,4,5,-9];
var sumArray = [];
var len = a.length;

for(var i = 0; i< len; i++){
  for(var j = i+1; j< len; j++){
    sumArray.push({
      o1: a[i],
      o2: a[j],
      sum: a[i] + a[j]
    })
  }
}

sumArray.sort(function(a,b){  
  return Math.abs(a.sum) - Math.abs(b.sum)
})

console.log(sumArray)
```

Comment: You'd be wasting O(n^2) space that you don't really need; it suffices to keep track of the pair (xi,xj) that minimizes |xi+xj|.

Comment: @blazs In my understanding its `2n log(n)`, but not very good with it. Another optimisation idea I had was to break loop on first `0` value, but will not be much.

Comment: There are {n choose 2} = n(n-1) / 2 = O(n^2) different unordered pairs of indices {i,j}, and if you save the sums of all pairs of elements, that's potentially O(n^2) different sums.

Answer (score 0):

**Find a Pair Whose Sum is Closest to zero in Array in Java**

```
package yourPackageNameGoesHere;

public class FindAPairWhoseSumIsClosestToZeroInArray {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int array[]={1,3,-5,7,8,20,-40,6};
    findAPairWhoseSumIsClosestToZeroInArray(array);
}

public static void findAPairWhoseSumIsClosestToZeroInArray(int[] nums) {
    if (nums.length < 2) return;
    int minimumSum = nums[0] + nums[1];
    int pairFirstIndex = 0, pairSecondIndex = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            int tempSum = nums[i] + nums[j];
            if (Math.abs(tempSum) < Math.abs(minimumSum)) {
                minimumSum = tempSum;
                pairFirstIndex = i;
                pairSecondIndex = j;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The pair whose sum is closest to zero : "+nums[pairFirstIndex]+" and "+nums[pairSecondIndex]);
}
```

}